# How do you mock the named export "uuidv4" using Jest and CommonJS?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I give up.  I can't figure out how to get my module to use my mock of the CommonJS named export `uuidv4`.  I've tried using `jest.mock()`, `jest.spyOn()`, and just setting the function equal to a `jest.fn()` as shown below (which is what I typically and successfully use in my other tests), but none of these approaches are working for me.

Here is the essence of the last testing attempt mentioned above:

```js
// myModule.test.js

const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const myModule = require('./myModule');

describe(`Tests for myModule'`, () => {
  test(`First test`, async () => {
    uuidv4 = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce("custom-uuid");

    await myModule.someFunction();

    expect(uuidv4).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

```js
// myModule.js

const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

async function someFunction() {
    const id = uuidv4();
    // ...do stuff with 'id'
}

module.exports = {someFunction};
```

No matter which approach I've tried (of the 3 mentioned above), I just can't get `myModule.someFunction` to make use of the mock I've created in my test for `uuidv4`.

Anyone know how to do this without using manual mocks?

Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work using the answer found here.

https://ilikekillnerds.com/2020/04/how-to-mock-uuid-in-jest/

One thing I'm making a note for myself about this is that this worked...

```js
jest.mock("../../../../../../functions/api/node_modules/uuid", () => ({ v4: () => "2306beb3-8833-40a5-b3f4-a8daab755251" }));
```

...but this did not...

```js
const rootDir = "../../../../../..";
const uuidModule = `${rootDir}/functions/api/node_modules/uuid`;
jest.doMock(uuidModule, () => ({ v4: () => "2306beb3-8833-40a5-b3f4-a8daab755251" }));
```